# Bind an Existing Object to a ComboBox in WPF C# MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, combobox

I am attempting to use a `ComboBox` to bind to a list of `CostCodes`. A record named `SelectedRecord` is passed in to be edited and I want two things to happen. Firstly, I want the `ComboBox` to select the `CostCode` that has already been applied to the `SelectedRecord`. I then want the user to be able to edit the `CostCode` so that they can assign the `SelectedRecord` to a different one.

I have successfully bound my `ComboBox` to an `ObservableCollection<CostCode>`, however when the user loads the `Window` the `CostCode` that is already assigned to the `SelectedRecord` is not selected automatically in the `ComboBox`. Here is the XAML:

```
<TextBox Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding SelectedRecord.Provider}"/>
<TextBox Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding SelectedRecord.Number}"/>
<ComboBox Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="1" 
            ItemsSource="{Binding AllCostCodes}"
            DisplayMemberPath="Text">
</ComboBox>
```

I've tried using `SelectedValue` and `SelectedValuePath` but no luck. Although the user is able to edit and the `CostCodes` are displayed correctly when the user clicks on the `ComboBox`, the `CostCode` already assigned to the `SelectedRecord` is not displayed. I Included a couple of `TextBoxes` to show how I am binding to those, I effectively want to do exactly the same with their `Text` properties but with the `ComboBox` instead.

EDIT: `CostCode.cs`

```
public partial class CostCode
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public CostCode()
    {
        this.PhoneRecords = new HashSet<PhoneRecord>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<PhoneRecord> PhoneRecords { get; set; }
}
```

`PhoneRecord.cs`

```
public partial class PhoneRecord
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> DateGiven { get; set; }
    public string PersonName { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> PhoneModelId { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> NMU { get; set; }
    public string IMEI { get; set; }
    public string Number { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> CostCodeId { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> DateReturned { get; set; }
    public string WhyReturned { get; set; }
    public string Solution { get; set; }
    public string Internet { get; set; }
    public string Provider { get; set; }
    public string SpeedDial { get; set; }
    public string OnDatabases { get; set; }
    public string Notes { get; set; }

    public virtual CostCode CostCode { get; set; }
    public virtual PhoneModel PhoneModel { get; set; }
}
```

`SelectedRecord` is chosen in a `DataGrid` of `PhoneRecords` then passed to an `EditWindow` where I want to set the applicable `CostCode`.

Comment: What type is SelectedRecord.CostCode? Is it the CostCode class? What are the members of the CostCode class?

Comment: `SelectedRecord` is of type `PhoneRecord`. `CostCode` is of type `CostCode`. Each `PhoneRecord` has a `CostCode` assigned to it.

Comment: What are the members of the CostCode class?

Comment: `Id` and `Text` are the properties.

Comment: Please post your code where the SelectedRecord is set along with all relevant types.

Comment: @mm8 Please see my edit. Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use **SelectedItem**.
Something like this:

```
<ComboBox Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="1" 
            ItemsSource="{Binding AllCostCodes}"
            DisplayMemberPath="Text"
            SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedRecord.CostCode}">
</ComboBox>
```

**Edit:** 
Just as Spongebrot and Ed Plunkett says in the comments: If it is not the same instance of the CodeCode-object then you need to override the Equals method the the CostCode object.
(In this edit I also chaned the binding from "SelectedRecord" to "SelectedRecord.CostCode" based on comments in your question.)

**Edit 2:**
You can read about overriding Equals at [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms173147(v=vs.80).aspx).
In your case I think it should be like this:

```
class CostCode
{
    //... property definition of Id and Text


    public override bool Equals(System.Object obj)
    {
        // If parameter is null return false.
        if (obj as  == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        // If parameter cannot be cast to CostCode return false.
        CostCode cc = obj as CostCode;
        if (cc == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        // Return true if the Id fields match:
        return Id == cc.Id;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return Id; // If Id is int...
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately it still doesn't Bind. Even if I do {SelectedRecord.CostCode}

Comment: Have you tried overriding the Equals method on the CostCode class and setting the Binding mode to TwoWay?

Comment: @Spongebrot The binding mode is TwoWay by default. But you may be right that he's got two different instances of the "same" CostCode.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I've got a `CostCode` that's on a `PhoneRecord` and then the `ComboBox` that is filled with a collection of type `CostCode`. I want to select the `CostCode` in the `ComboBox` collection that relates to the `CostCode` on the passed `PhoneRecord`. Would I need to override the equals method to do that? In what way would I override it?

Comment: The CostCode must have some kind of unique Property, or combination of properties. If its just a single property like lets say a Id you could also use SelectedValue and SelectedValuePath, where the Binding of the SelectedValue would point to the Id of the Selected CostCode {Binding SelectedRecord.CostCode.Id} and the SelectedValuePath would be "Id". If its a combination of properties like name+value you would have to override the Equals Method, which just compares two objects and returns true if they are the same.

Comment: @CBreeze did you try to just copy the Equals example to your CostCode class?

Comment: @Björn I just tried, that has actually worked. I'm not sure why so I'm going to need to do some reading to understand. Can you reference anywhere where this is explained? I found the MDSN site to be quite poor.

Comment: Good! The reason it didn't work without Equals was because SelectedRecord.CostCode wasn't pointing to the exact same instance found in AllCostCodes, even though they have the same Id. Read this for more information: https://grantwinney.com/how-to-compare-two-objects-testing-for-equality-in-c/  And please mark my answer as correct if it was helpful to you.

Comment: @CBreeze Please mark my answer as correct or add your own answer and mark it as correct (as I understand that you have found a working solution).